# Jenkins build and test over ssh

Tags: php, testing, ant, jenkins, phpunit

I have a system with Jenkins, Ant, PHP, PHPunit among other php tools.

Is it possible to make Jenkins push the into a remote server, use Ant to run the Tests and them retrieve the data about the tests?

Comment: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Job-type-Monitor-an-external-job-td3901007.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a separate ant-script and use ssh-support of ant for the tasks. The ssh-tasks worked very well for some of my projects in the past. This way Jenkins would run a local ant-build, which internally does all the remote access.

Another plus of this would be that you can manually run the ant-script (even parts of it) whenever necessary, which makes development and testing of it much easier.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html for documentation of the ssh-related tasks in Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins supports distributed build(can distribute almost any thing ) and unified reporting.  See  [distributed build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).

There are suite of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Pluginsbytopic) to make the distribution and data collection better - Specifically build wrappers.